# get list of available ip addresses in subnet

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

How can i get the list of available ip address in a subnet?
I was able to get the list of all ip addresses but not able to check if the ip address is already utilized. for some reason the below command doesn't work.
Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: For AZ CLI (preview) `az network vnet subnet list-available-ips --resource-group myrg --vnet-name my-vnet -n mysnet --query [0:3] `

Answer (score 4):

> For some reason the below command doesn't work.
>   Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability

We can use Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgname | Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability -IPAddress "10.0.1.10"
```

Also we can use PowerShell to list available ip address in a subnet, here is my script:

```
PS C:\> $vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name "vnet" -ResourceGroupName "jason"
PS C:\> $networkID = "10.0.0."
PS C:\> For ($i=1; $i -lt 255; $i++)
>> {
>>     $IP = $networkID + $i
>>     $Address = Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability -VirtualNetwork $vnet -IPAddress $IP
>>     If ($Address.Available –eq $False) { Write-Host "$IP is not available" -ForegroundColor Red }
>>     else { Write-Host "$IP is available" -ForegroundColor Green}
>> }
10.0.0.1 is not available
10.0.0.2 is not available
10.0.0.3 is not available
10.0.0.4 is not available
10.0.0.5 is available
10.0.0.6 is available
10.0.0.7 is available
10.0.0.8 is available
10.0.0.9 is available
10.0.0.10 is available
```

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability works for VMs but I have a subnet for Redis and Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability giving true, even if those IP addresses is assigned to Redis cache (don't trust to these availabilities for

Answer (score 2):

I have the following example and it is working as expected. I am using ` backtick character to separate my commands into multiple lines.

```
$vNetName = "myvirtualnetworkname"
$resourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup"
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork `
-Name $vNetName `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
| Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability -IPAddress "10.0.0.10"
```

I am piping into `Test-AzureRMPrivateIPAddressAvailability` command so it didn't provide resource group or vnetname in that command. If you use that command by its own then you will have to provide resource group name and vnet name.