# Is there a way to print all IP Addresses in an azure subnet with Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I can use Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig to get the subnet configuration and it has the property of AddressSpace. That outputs a string value of to space, but I can't find a way to output each IP address. I'm looking for a way to get the last IP address in the Address space.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774085/get-list-of-available-ip-addresses-in-subnet ?

Comment: Yes but this is checking what's available by supplying the IP address. I need to have a script that doesn't know the IP address at all and can calculate the last IP address in the space

Comment: not sure calculating the last IP will do you any good.  While it may work at first, as you add/remove machines in no particular order, knowing the last IP given may not lead to the desired result.

Comment: Usually, the IP assignment starts from the fifth to the end in order. And there also Reserved the broadcast IP. If you do not assign yourself the last IP always the Countdown first except the broadcast IP. Also, you can have a check on the availability of the IP first.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
$network = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -name 'some-vnet' -ResourceGroupName 'some-network-resourcegroup'
($network.SubnetsText | ConvertFrom-Json).IpConfigurations
```